# unable to use darken if color variable has important flag

Tags: sass

I use darken to define another color, however if the base color has important flag, it fails to compile. This is my scss

```
$baseColor: #FF6600 !important;

.my-link:active {
    color: darken($baseColor, 20%);
}
```

and this is the error
    ... (#FF6600 !important) is not a color for 'darken'

If I change important to default, everything works fine. I do need important flag as this variable is overwritten in different places. I'm wondering how I can fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is quite clearly telling you what's wrong.  You're trying to pass in a list containing a color (`#FF6600`) and a string (`!important`) to a function that is expecting a color.  The `!default` flag is not a string, it is a Sass language construct.

If you need to use `!important` often enough that you need to use it every time you use this variable, I strongly recommend that you reevaluate your code.  This is considered to be a code smell.

If you *really really really* need it, you have to use the `nth()` function to extract the first element of the list.

```
$baseColor: #FF6600 !important;

.my-link:active {
    color: darken(nth($baseColor, 1), 20%) nth($baseColor, 2);
}
```

Note that this will raise an error if your variable is not actually a list (because you're trying to select an element that doesn't exist).  If you don't actually need `!important` here, then this will work fine with or without a list:

```
$baseColor: #FF6600 !important;

.my-link:active {
    color: darken(nth($baseColor, 1), 20%);
}
```